# LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I started to learn Java and i'm trying to use Spring Data MongoDB (See http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods).

But when i added @EnableJpaRepositories i get an error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@13271bd: startup date [Mon Oct 03 08:39:58 YEKT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:416) [spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:997) [spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956) [spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:818) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at hello.Application.main(Application.java:10) [classes!/:0.1.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_76]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_76]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_76]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_76]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [gs-messaging-stomp-websocket-0.1.0.jar:0.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [gs-messaging-stomp-websocket-0.1.0.jar:0.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [gs-messaging-stomp-websocket-0.1.0.jar:0.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58) [gs-messaging-stomp-websocket-0.1.0.jar:0.1.0]
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>gs-messaging-stomp-websocket</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>sockjs-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>stomp-websocket</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.3</version>
    </dependency>




    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Remove `@EnableJpaRepository` Spring boot already does that for you (also for MongoDb so you wouldn't need `@EnableMongoRepository` either)` alsi instead of dependencies on `spring-data-mongodb` and `spring-data-jpa` use the respective starters instead `spring-boot-starter-data-mongo` and `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`. That way you now you have the right version for both dependencies.